# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 227

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, connection-string

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CentralDb" connectionString=
     "metadata=.\CentralDb.csdl|.\CentralDb.ssdl|.\CentralDb.msl;
      provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
      provider connection string=CentralDb&quot;Data Source=U19675709\SQLEXPRESS&quot;Initial Catalog=CentralDb&quot;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False&quot;" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 
          <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString=
     "metadata=.\CentralDb.csdl|.\CentralDb.ssdl|.\CentralDb.msl;
      provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
      provider connection string=CentralDb&quot;Data Source=U19675709\SQLEXPRESS&quot;Initial Catalog=CentralDb&quot;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False&quot;" 
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /> 

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I'm trying to create a connection string for an EntityFramework utilising database.

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 227.

...is the error I receive when trying to run  with my above **web.config**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string seems to have extra quotation marks (`&quot`) inside its `DataSource` description, and also, just before it, it appears to have an extra `CentralDb`at the beginning of the `provider connection string`.

Try this instead:

```
<add name="CentralDb" connectionString=
 "metadata=.\CentralDb.csdl|.\CentralDb.ssdl|.\CentralDb.msl;
  provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
  provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=U19675709\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CentralDb;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=False&quot;" 
  providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```